# My w3 Accordion Menu does not expand in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

my accordion menu seems to work on firefox, but not on chrome. When clicking on it it doesn't expand. This is the error using chrome inspect: Uncaught ReferenceError: myAccFunc is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick. I used the code from w3.css.

Here is the html:

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<head>
<title>
  My Homework Site
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/Site.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/style.css"/>

<div id="container" class = "row" style="height: 9000px;">
<div id="menu" class = "col" style ="max-width: 210px; height: 100%;">
<div class="menu">
</div>
<button class="w3-button w3-block w3-left-align" onclick="myAccFunc()">
                Labs <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div id="demoAcc" class="w3-hide w3-white w3-card">
<a href="labs/lab3/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab3</a><br />
<a href="labs/lab4/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab4</a><br />
<a href="labs/lab5/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab5</a><br />
<a href="labs/lab6/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab6</a><br />
<a href="labs/lab7/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab7</a><br />
<a href="labs/lab8/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab8</a><br />
<a href="labs/lab9/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab9</a><br />
<a href="labs/lab10/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab10</a><br />
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```js
function myAccFunc() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demoAcc");
    if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
      x.className += " w3-show";
      x.previousElementSibling.className += " w3-green";
    } else { 
      x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
      x.previousElementSibling.className = 
      x.previousElementSibling.className.replace(" w3-green", "");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Its because script is not loaded before the HTML loads.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: i have answered try that method. Hope that helps.

Comment: Let me know if its all working.

Comment: it is still the same

Comment: Really! Here is working demo: try on chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/7wbjos4y/11/

Comment: ok it seems as though chrome is not updating for some reason. so i would save the new script(which works on that link you sent me), yet looking at inspect it is not there. So for some reason even though i refresh the page it is not updating. Right now it looks as though there is no java script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple methods you can try to load script before the DOM is ready.

You can use `window.functionName = function(){}` or `$(document).ready(function() {}`

```js
window.myAccFunc = function() {
     var x = document.getElementById("demoAcc");
     if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
      x.className += " w3-show";
      x.previousElementSibling.className += " w3-green";
    } else { 
      x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
       x.previousElementSibling.className = 
      x.previousElementSibling.className.replace(" w3-green", "");
    }
 }
```

```html
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<head>
<title>
  My Homework Site
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/Site.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/style.css"/>

<div id="container" class = "row" style="height: 9000px;">
<div id="menu" class = "col" style ="max-width: 210px; height: 100%;">
<div class="menu">
</div>
<button class="w3-button w3-block w3-left-align" onclick="myAccFunc()">
                Labs <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div id="demoAcc" class="w3-hide w3-white w3-card">
<a href="labs/lab3/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab3</a><br />
<a href="labs/lab4/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab4</a><br />
<a href="labs/lab5/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab5</a><br />
<a href="labs/lab6/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab6</a><br />
<a href="labs/lab7/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab7</a><br />
<a href="labs/lab8/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab8</a><br />
<a href="labs/lab9/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab9</a><br />
<a href="labs/lab10/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Lab10</a><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because your script is running after your html is load, you need to do something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

<head>
  <title>
    My Homework Site
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

<body>
  <p> some html</p>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/Site.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Actually its the other way around. Script is not loaded before the DOM is ready. Hence why the function become not defined.

Comment: thank you for the correction, that was what I wanted to say.

Comment: I have a rotating picture banner at the top of the page, and it just caused that to go whack. Instead of rotating, all 11 pictures ended up displaying in a line over the accordion menu.